# align elements in center and to the left

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment, center

I need to align my list items like in the picture(in the bottom that dropdown).

[image: menu]

As you can see they are centered but alson aligned in a line vertically. How can I achive this?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="footer">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="container">
                     <ul id="insurances">
                        <li><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/estate-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia nieruchomości</a></li>
                        <li><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/tourist-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia turystycznego</a></li>
                        <li><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/health-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia zdrowotnego</a></li>
                        <li><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/car-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia samochodu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/assistance-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia assistance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/NNW-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia NNW</a></li>
                        <li><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/law-insurance.png">Ochrony prawnej</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Szukam</p>
                    <a class="insurance-type">
                        <span>Ubezpieczenia nieruchomości</span>
                    </a>

                    <div clas="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And Css

```
    .footer .outer .container ul {
    position: absolute;
    border:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    bottom:110px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display:none;
}

    .footer .outer .container ul li a img {
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.footer .outer .container ul li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;

}
.footer .outer .container ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:21px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;

}
```

Would be thankful for any proposals

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: please provide a online demo

Answer (score 0):

Mocked something quickly, possibly this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/kasperoo/eHLBu/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <ul id="insurances">
    <li><p><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/estate-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia nieruchomości</a></p></li>
     <li><p><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/estate-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia nieruchomości</a></p></li>
     <li><p><a href="conditions-form.html"><img src="img/estate-insurance.png">Ubezpieczenia nieruchomości</a></p></li>
</ul>


.container {
    position: relative;    
}
#insurances {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
}
#insurances li p {
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#insurances li:nth-child(even) {
    background: green; 
}
#insurances li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: grey; 
}
```

Comment: this works fine, but what i need is my elements to be aligned in line with the logo. So they should be centered meaning that their left side has to be in the center and they should expand to the right whatever space they need. This is difficult because as I increase the size o <p> tag, they start shifting to the left more.

Comment: Looks like you need to do some JS calculations: http://jsfiddle.net/kasperoo/eHLBu/3/ and also if you require, amend the margin on window resize